# Packaging multiple programs into one installer C# (visual 2010 basic)

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, installation

I am currently finishing a project that uses multiple programs, and I am trying to get ideas of how to package them all into one installer, probably through the publishing option in visual basic, but I am sure there are multiple ways this can be done.

First, the main program is done using windows forms. That program, on the server side, keeps track of information that is going on in the warehouse. Users are able to manipulate that info on the client side as needed from multiple points: receiving, work orders, and shipping.

The external program was done in Unity and uses the same information to show how the warehouse is staged, what work is being done, and gives a 3D view of where people and inventory are located in snap shots of time.

So what I am trying to do, is package the Unity project into the installer. It's okay that it's a stand alone program, since I can just open it via the system controls in the main windows form project.

What isn't okay, is that right now it takes two installs to get everything running. Given that I have to deal with individuals that can barely use Google chat, I need this process to be seamless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am personally a fan of [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org). I have used it for small, single application distributions and large composite applications that involve many parts. It is capable of producing MSI( MSU, MSM, etc.), EXE installers and has Visual Studio integration.

Comment: I don't have the rep to post more than 1 link in my response. So...[[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163456.aspx)][[2](http://www.ita-software.com/papers/borup_wix.htm)]